# Strange border after closing Popup

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, border, windows-store-apps

After closing a Popup a strange border appears one of a Page element. (Page is parent of a Popup)
Do you know the reason? Or maybe know the name of property that trigger this border?

[image: strange border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button has Focus. That is the Focused state. It's part of the standard Windows Store XAML template. It's contained in the StandardStyles.xaml file.

```
<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
```

Some of the key pieces (this would be for the dark theme for example):

```
<Rectangle
    x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
    IsHitTestVisible="False"
    Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
    StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
    StrokeDashArray="1,1"
    Opacity="0"
    StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>


<VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1"
                Duration="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                To="1"
                Duration="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <!-- ... etc... -->
</VisualStateGroup>
```

While you could disable it or remove it, you might want to just move focus somewhere else when the popup closes, as it's a visual indicator for keyboard/assistive-control users that the back button has focus. You should be able to press the TAB key a few times to cause it to show without using the popup.

Comment: you are right, but how to make a focus hidden? By default when a  LayoutAwarePage starts, nothing has got his focus border.

Comment: Something has focus -- it just may not show it initially. When the popup closes ... what do you want to have focus? You could activate the "Unfocused" VisualState for the button, which would hide the focus rectangle (but you may not want it to have focus anyway).